# Can you recommend a good tutorial on building custom package versions?

Tags: apt, packaging, dpkg

After installing Ubuntu 11.04 I was disappointed by the fact there are still Scala 2.7 (when 2.8 is long ago current actual branch) and Mono 2.6 (when pretty a time has passed after 2.8 release). I am not sure I could build all the packages for Mono myself, but I'd like to try making my own custom version of Scala package (and I want my system to accept it not as a different package but a version of the original, so that if I put it into a configured repository, the system will automatically upgrade to it from currently installed original 2.7).

Can you recommend a good tutorial on this subject (Ubuntu deb packages building and hacking for beginners)?

Answer (score 3):

The "[Updating an Ubuntu Package](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/udd-merging.html)" section of the Packaging Guide is a good place to start.

Comment: Broken link. Did you mean [this guide?](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/)

Comment: Fixed thanks! Remember you can submit fixes to any broken link on the site by clicking "Improve this post"!

Comment: Both the link in the answer, and the suggestion in the comment are broken now.    I can't find a page on the current ubuntu wiki with a title similar to either so I can't suggest a suitable replacement without viewing the original pages for comparison... catch-22.